# Stripping the_content() from images then displaying them seperately

Tags: images, content

Ok, I've got content with images removed using this code:

```
$content = strip_tags(get_the_content(), '<p><a><h2><blockquote><code><ul><li><i><em><strong>');
$content = preg_replace("/\[caption.*\[\/caption\]/", '', $content);
$content = str_replace("[/caption]", '', $content);
echo $content;
```

Now I want to show the images at the end.  I'm trying to use this:

```
$images = strip_tags(get_the_content(), '<img>');
echo $images;
```

But it's not working.  Any ideas?

Comment: I guess I should clarify. When I use this code, it first shows the content without images, which I expected, then it shows all the content including images.

Answer (score 1):

maybe use this regex:

```
$pattern = "/<a(.*?)href=('|\")([^>]*)('|\")(.*?)><img(.*?)src=('|\")([^>]*).(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)('|\")(.*?)class=('|\")([^>]*)('|\")(.*?)\/><\/a>/i";



function example_replace ($content) {
   global $post;

   $pattern = "/<a(.*?)href=('|\")([^>]*)('|\")(.*?)><img(.*?)src=('|\")([^>]*).(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)('|\")(.*?)class=('|\")([^>]*)('|\")(.*?)\/><\/a>/i";
   $replacement = '<a$1href=$2$3$4$5><img$6src=$7$8.$9$10$11class=$12$13 <strong>imagelink</strong>$14$15$16/><\/a>';
   $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);

   return $content;
}
```

Comment: maybe small one is enough: <img([^<>+]*)>
see: http://regexr.com?2usnk